# Vim popup menu, like the omni autocomplete popup

Tags: vim

I'm making a Vim Script. I want to make a popup that offers alternatives. It should work the same as the Omni-popup, but not replace the string or go through the omni functions. Like this:

[image]

I've haxxed in the functionality I need by using the `completefunc` and the auto command event `CompleteDone`, just to get the popup. But it's really ugly and messy, since I'm not using it for auto completion.

Is there a way to use this popup but with full control, not going through the omni-complete functionality? Like populating it with values and receive the value selected?

I know you can just place the alternatives in an other buffer and just grab the input from there. But it disturbs the work flow, I want a popup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The insert mode popup menu is only meant for completions, as you've correctly found out. There is not other precedence for popup menus as a general selector in Vim, so such functionality is not there and is difficult to emulate. (In GVIM, one can populate a right mouse button popup menu, but this would need to be triggered by a mouse key press.)

The "Vim way" would be to `:echo` the list of menu items and query (via `getchar()` or `input()`), or just use `confirm()` or `inputlist()`. Examples built into Vim are the query in `:tselect`.

Plugins often use a split *scratch buffer* to build a more elaborate menu; this can even be combined with `'completefunc'`, as any text entry into the scratch buffer is discarded, anyway.

The [FuzzyFinder - buffer/file/command/tag/etc explorer](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1984) plugin uses this, and even provides an API for custom uses, cp. `:help fuf-callbackitem-mode`. That's certainly worth a look, though the menu would still be located at the top, not inside the current buffer.

Answer (score 0):

Do either of these do what you want?

```
:help inputdialog()
:help inputlist()
```

Comment: Unfortunately not, although this was kind of smooth, it does print the alternatives in the command line, not like a popup as illustrated in the picture.